# Streaming Pipeline in Dataflow to Bigtable Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I wanted to read the pubsub topic and write data to BigTable with the dataflow code written in Python. I could find the sample code in JAVA but not in Python.
How can we assign columns in a row from pubsub to different column families and write the data to Bigtable?

Comment: Hi @Priya Agarwal. If any below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Let us know otherwise if the given answers still don't solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To write to Bigtable in a Dataflow pipeline, you'll need to create direct rows and pass them to the `WriteToBigTable` doFn. Here is a brief example that just passes in the row keys and adds one cell for each key nothing too fancy:

```
import datetime
import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio import WriteToBigTable
from google.cloud.bigtable import row


class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--bigtable-project',
            help='The Bigtable project ID, this can be different than your '
                 'Dataflow project',
            default='bigtable-project')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--bigtable-instance',
            help='The Bigtable instance ID',
            default='bigtable-instance')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--bigtable-table',
            help='The Bigtable table ID in the instance.',
            default='bigtable-table')


class CreateRowFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, key):
        direct_row = row.DirectRow(row_key=key)
        direct_row.set_cell(
            "stats_summary",
            b"os_build",
            b"android",
            datetime.datetime.now())
        return [direct_row]


def run(argv=None):
    """Build and run the pipeline."""
    options = MyOptions(argv)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        p | beam.Create(["phone#4c410523#20190501",
                         "phone#4c410523#20190502"]) | beam.ParDo(
            CreateRowFn()) | WriteToBigTable(
            project_id=options.bigtable_project,
            instance_id=options.bigtable_instance,
            table_id=options.bigtable_table)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I am just starting to explore this now and can link to a more polished version on GitHub once it's complete. Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: I wanted dataflow pipeline to read from pubsub and write to bigtable. The code you provided doesn't read from pubsub and is not a dataflow code. You are directly using Python client libraries to insert data to Bigtable.

Comment: Hey Priya, sorry for the delay, but I finally got around to playing around with this and put together some code that should be helpful. Let me know if this works or if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks Billy. I'll have a look at that and will post the updates.

Comment: If this was able to help, please mark as accepted or let me know if something didn't work, thanks!

Comment: @BillyJacobson Why isn't all this covered in the Bigtable or Dataflow docs?

Comment: @BillyJacobson I've tried your code, and it is throwing an error in cloud logging. 

raise exc.with_traceback(traceback): File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1213, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 570, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File "<ipython-input-5-562e483bc825>", line 3, in process NameError: name 'row' is not defined [while running '[10]: ParDo(CreateRowFn)-ptransform-85']

I've already imported from google.cloud.bigtable import row

Comment: I've solved that problem by writing the import statement within the ParDo function just before row is called. The pipeline seems to work already. However this gets even more disappointing.....eventhough the pipeline is working and I see the data being processed by the WriteToBigtable node.... it doesn't show up in Bigtable. I'm querying the row key and I can't get anything out. So so so frustrating using Dataflow and Bigtable.There isn't a shred of good answers anywhere.

Comment: Sorry about the frustration, you might have better luck with Java. This is in the queue to be added to the official docs and then the code sample can be tested and maintained to ensure you don't have to face this kind of problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of what was proposed and adding PubSub, here’s a working version..

**Pre requisites**

- GCS Bucket created (for Dataflow temp/staging files)
- PubSub topic created
- PubSub subscription created
- BigTable instance created
- BigTable table created
- BigTable **column family must be created** (no visible error otherwise !)

Example of the latter with `cbt`:

`cbt -instance test-instance createfamily test-table cf1`

**Code**

Define and run the Dataflow pipeline.

```
# Packages

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio import WriteToBigTable
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# Classes
 
class CreateRowFn(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, pipeline_options):
        
        self.instance_id = pipeline_options.bigtable_instance
        self.table_id = pipeline_options.bigtable_table
  
    def process(self, key):
        
        from google.cloud.bigtable import row
        import datetime

        direct_row = row.DirectRow(row_key=key)
        direct_row.set_cell(
            'cf1',
            'field1',
            'value1',
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
        
        yield direct_row

# Options

class XyzOptions(PipelineOptions):
    
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--bigtable_project', default='nested'),
        parser.add_argument('--bigtable_instance', default='instance'),
        parser.add_argument('--bigtable_table', default='table')

pipeline_options = XyzOptions(
    save_main_session=True, streaming=True,
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project=PROJECT,
    region=REGION,
    temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION,
    staging_location=STAGING_LOCATION,
    requirements_file=REQUIREMENTS_FILE,
    bigtable_project=PROJECT,
    bigtable_instance=INSTANCE,
    bigtable_table=TABLE)

# Pipeline

def run (argv=None):
    
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
       
       input_subscription=f"projects/{PROJECT}/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION}"

        _ = (p
                | 'Read from Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
                | 'Conversion UTF-8 bytes to string' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: msg.decode('utf-8'))
                | 'Conversion string to row object' >> beam.ParDo(CreateRowFn(pipeline_options)) 
                | 'Writing row object to BigTable' >> WriteToBigTable(project_id=pipeline_options.bigtable_project,
                                  instance_id=pipeline_options.bigtable_instance,
                                  table_id=pipeline_options.bigtable_table))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Publish a message `b"phone#1111"` to PubSub topic (e.g. using the Python PublisherClient()).

**Table content** (using happybase)

```
b'phone#1111': {b'cf1:field1': b'value1'}
Row length: 1
```

Comment: In my pipeline I have a `CreateRowFn` function which is doing the same thing as yours, but I keep getting the following error when setting the cell data on the `row.set_cell(...)` method: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Mutation'>: attribute lookup Mutation on __main__ failed [while running 'Transform to BigTable row']`

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm getting the above error when _yielding_ the `DirectRow` object from the `CreateRowFn` function.

Comment: @James B: Did you find a way to fix your issue ?

Comment: I pinned (downgraded) `google-cloud-bigtable` to version `1.7.0` and it fixed the error.